# Teaching about derivatives - how to avoid students getting confused?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, education

Well, it's a bit tricky one.

I am to give a, let's say, lecture concerning the basics of calculus (note: I'm just a student). My audience is, let's say, not very *keen* on maths (they're mostly physics students) and I know there's no point in even trying to make them understand the Cauchy "$\varepsilon-\delta$" definition of limit and so forth. Instead, I'm going to focus mainly on applications of derivatives and integrals in computing moments of inertia *etc.*

But here's my concern. In modern calculus, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is no longer a *ratio*, for it's a *operator*. Yet physicists tend to manipulate with derivatives as they still were fractions (you know - $u=x^2\rightarrow du=2xdx\rightarrow xdx=\frac{du}{2}$). In *most* cases, though not entirely rigorous, such manipulations yelds correct results.

And here is my question. I have to introduce the definition $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$

How should I tell them, that while the upper is the *modern* and *rigorous* definition of a limit, manipulating with $dy$ and $dx$ mostly *works*, but can yeld some absurd results and thus we have to watch out?  How to avoid them getting confused? How to cope with, frankly, treating derivatives in two ways? Pay attention that *they are not maths students* and there is no point in making them learn calculus in an entirely rigorous way...

I have some experience in teaching, but this is the topic I'm particularly concerned with and I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is it possible to classify (rigorously) when such manipulations are valid, and when they are not? Such manipulations are a useful (time-saving) heuristic, and you're worried when they'll go wrong. So it would be nice if you could point out when

Comment: Well, here's the problem.  *Rigorously*. By no means with "epsilons-deltas" and so forth. They are, well, *physicists*...

Comment: I meant maybe you can provide another rule of thumb (which you know to be true) which suggests to them (without proof) when their heuristic will work, and when there's a chance it won't. Might be a lot to hope for I guess

Comment: I'm a physicist and I think that also physicists can understand ( and use) the $\epsilon \delta$ machinery. Anyway the ''not entirely rigorous'' use of the Leibniz notation is very useful and we can avoid oddities if we give attention to the case in wich a function is not invertible, such that, from the existence of $dx/dt$,  we cannot say that $dt/dx=(dx/dt)^{-1}$

Comment: I did not mean to offend physicists in any way. I'm a physicist myself, and I'm aware that physicists are often able to learn and use the "$\varepsilon\delta$ machinery" as you put it. The problem is that... well, let's put this straight. *These students are not the smartest ones*. They *already* tend to have problems with math. That's why I said it's a *tricky question*. In my opinion - based on my observations and suggestions from my teachers - I should avoid detailed formalism *as much as possible*. My concern is the "heuristic" use of Leibnitz notation.

Comment: So your concern is mostly about playing with the change of variable $x= f(y), dx = f'(y) dy$ in $\int$ ?

Comment: In that case you need to prove the change of variable rigorously, and try to explain how this is compatible with the notation $dx/dy$ and some algebraic manipulation